# Passing modified user defined properties to auth

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am to trying to evaluate a user's role as soon as they login into the system so i can avoid querying the database every time a user's role needs to be evaluated that is to say running `auth()->user()->role->role_name`.

Here is a look at my User model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

Use App\Library\Hash;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public $is_admin;

    public $is_employer;

    // Pagination size
    protected $perPage = 10;

    // Table name
    protected $table = 'user';

    // Primary Key
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    // Add new datetime column for carbon use
    protected $dates = ['last_login', ];

    // User Role Foreign Key
    protected $userRoleForeignKey = 'role_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password', 'salt', 'email_hash', 'active'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'salt', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function checkUserRole() {
        $role = $this->role->role_name;

        if ( $role == 'admin' ) {
            $this->is_admin = true;
        } else if ( $role == 'employer' ) {
            $this->is_employer = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo(
                'App\UserRole',
                $this->userRoleForeignKey
            );
    }
```

As you can see i have added two properties at the top of my class `$is_admin` and  `$is_employer` to help me determine a user's role and i have also added the method `checkUserRole` run every time a user is logging in.

Below is the `login` method in the `SessionsController`

```
    public function login(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
            ], [
                'email.required' => 'Email is required',
                'password.required' => 'Password is required',
            ]);

        $user = User::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();

        if ( !$user || !($user->checkCredentials($request->password)) ) {
            return back()->with([
                    'class' => 'alert-danger',
                    'message' => 'Please check your credentials'
                ]);
        }

        $user = $user->checkUserRole();

        auth()->login($user);

        dd( auth()->user() );

        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

Below is a screenshot from when i login as an employer and it hits the `dd` function.
[image]

As you see from the screenshot, the `$is_employer` property is set to true.

Problem is when i comment out the `dd` function in the `login` and am redirected to the dashboard controlled by the `index` method of the `DashboardController` class as shown below

```
public function index()
{
    dd( auth()->user()->is_employer );
}
```

I get the output of `null` from the `dd` function.

Why would the output be `null` when it is clearly showing it is true just before redirection?

Comment: Have you thought about using middleware to route the authenticated user to the correct place? Here's a link in case you want to look into it https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-middleware

Comment: @user10341554 Thank you but the link you are referring to shows only how to assign certain middleware to a certain group routes, it does not deal with my specific issue

Answer (score 1):

When you call `auth()->user()` you get a brand new instance of User. To achieve what you want you'll have to cache the role. Check out the documentation about caching, but a simple example would be `session()->put('some_key', 'some_value')`

Comment: Thank you i had thought of that, i was thinking of implementing it but thanks for the heads up anyway